# CMUSphinx error using Dutch : Decoder_setJsgfFile returned -1 Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Building an Android app with Speech recognition component. I've built a keyword .gram file, containing the 3.240 words I want to recognize. I've constructed a corresponding dictionary (phonetic), using http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html. This is English only.. I need a tool that will create a Dutch phonetic dictionary. Any suggestions?

When I try to point to the Dutch Acoustic model, downloaded at https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Dutch%20Voxforge, I get an error in my app (Decoder_setJsgfFile returned -1). The error is on line 43 of Decoder.class.

When I use "en-us-ptm", the application works, but recognition is terrible. Please provice guidance. Other suggestions for frameworks for recognizing 3.500 dutch words also welcome. Thank you.

Content of the DUTCH acoustic model folder created by lmtool :
feat.params
mdef
means
mixture_weights
noisedict
transition_matrices
variances

Edit : the Decoder_setJsgfFile returned -1 is a generic error. Check your logfile lines prior to this error for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in matching the dictionary with the grammar file. You need ALL words that are in your grammar file to be present in the dictionary, or the application will crash.

You could also look at Kaldi-asr for speech recognition, it has a nice Dutch language model (by TU Twente) available on git (Kaldi_NL).

Comment: Past few weeks, I did a lot of research on Kaldi for Dutch. It works pretty good, the results are very acceptable, so is speed. I run it on CentOS, you just need to install Python3 and then kaldi and KaldiNL..